# getting only last visible item on checking any checkbox in android custom listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a custom `listview` having checkbox and it has check all functionalty also. So I want all the checked items on button click, but when I check any checkbox I get only last visible item of `listview` and if I check all the checkboxes and click on button then I get value of last visible item multiple times. I don't know why this is happening, plz help me. Thanks in advance.
My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            status=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status);
            error=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
            status=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status);
            approve=(Button) findViewById(R.id.approve);
            reject=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reject);

            if (isNotAdded) {

                final View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_header,listView, false);
                cb1 = (CheckBox) headerView.findViewById(R.id.cb1);

                listAdapter=new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_view);


                Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
                //bundle_id = b.getString("string");
                bundle_id = "T0001";

                status_data=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.status);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,status_data);
                status.setAdapter(adapter);


                status.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                    {
                        status_changed=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                        if(status_changed.equals("Approved"))
                        {


                            LeaveApprovedStatus bkg=new  LeaveApprovedStatus(MainActivity.this);

                                bkg.execute(bundle_id);


                        }

                        else if(status_changed.equals("Rejected"))
                        {

                            LeaveRejectedStatus bkg=new  LeaveRejectedStatus(MainActivity.this);
                            bkg.execute(bundle_id);


                        }

                        else
                        {

                            LeavePendingStatus bkg=new  LeavePendingStatus(MainActivity.this);

                                bkg.execute(bundle_id);






                         }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}


                });


                cb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*
                    * Set all the checkbox to True/False
                    */
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    mChecked.put(i, cb1.isChecked());
                    }
                    /*
                    * Update View
                    */
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    });


                listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
                isNotAdded = false;
            }


            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            approve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(status_changed.equals("Approved"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already approved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String data=getData("Yes");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }


                }
            });



    }


    public final String getData(String decision){

        String json_string = null;

        if(status_changed.equals("Pending"))
        {
            empcode_list.clear();
            from.clear();
            to.clear();
            lv_type.clear();
            nod.clear();
            status_list.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                if (mChecked.get(i)) {


                    count=count+1;
                    empcode_list.add((String) listAdapter.detailsHolder.empcode.getText().toString());
                    from.add((String) listAdapter.detailsHolder.from.getText());
                    to.add((String) listAdapter.detailsHolder.to.getText());
                    lv_type.add((String) listAdapter.detailsHolder.lv_type.getText());
                    nod.add((String) listAdapter.detailsHolder.nod.getText());

                }
            }

            status_list.add(decision);




            JSONArray jArr1= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:empcode_list)
             {
               jArr1.put(data);
             }


            JSONArray jArr2= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:from)
             {
               jArr2.put(data);
             }

            JSONArray jArr3= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:to)
             {
               jArr3.put(data);
             }

            JSONArray jArr4= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:lv_type)
             {
               jArr4.put(data);
             }

            JSONArray jArr5= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:status_list)
             {
               jArr5.put(data);
             }

            JSONArray jArr6= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:nod)
             {
               jArr6.put(data);
             }

            JSONArray jArr7= new JSONArray();
            for(String data:remark)
             {
               jArr7.put(data);
             }

            JSONArray jArraySet = new JSONArray();
              jArraySet.put(jArr1);
              jArraySet.put(jArr2);
              jArraySet.put(jArr3);
              jArraySet.put(jArr4);
              jArraySet.put(jArr5);
              jArraySet.put(jArr6);
              jArraySet.put(jArr7);


              json_string=String.valueOf(jArraySet);

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        else {

          }

        return json_string;
    }




    //adapter class

        public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

             Context c;
             DetailsHolder detailsHolder;

            public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
                super(context, resource);
                this.c=context;


            }

            public void add(Details object) {

                super.add(object);
                list.add(object);
            }


            public void clearData() {
                list.clear();
            }

            public int getCount() {

                count=list.size();
                return count;
            }


            @Override
            public Details getItem(int position) {

                return (Details) list.get(position);
            }
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            row=convertView;
                //final DetailsHolder detailsHolder;
            //Toast.makeText(c, String.valueOf(list.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(row==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, parent, false);
                    detailsHolder=new DetailsHolder();
                    detailsHolder.empcode=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.empcode1);
                    detailsHolder.empname=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.empname1);
                    detailsHolder.appdate=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.appdate1);
                    detailsHolder.lv_type=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lv_type1);
                    detailsHolder.from=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.from1);
                    detailsHolder.to=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.to1);
                    detailsHolder.nod=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nod1);
                    detailsHolder.reason=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.reason1);
                    detailsHolder.status=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.status1);
                    detailsHolder.cb2=(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cb2);
                    detailsHolder.remark=(EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.remark);

                    row.setTag(detailsHolder);




                }
                else{

                    detailsHolder=(DetailsHolder) row.getTag();

                    }


                final Details details=(Details)this.getItem(position);
                detailsHolder.empcode.setText(details.getEmpcode());
                detailsHolder.empname.setText(details.getEmpname());
                detailsHolder.empname.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                detailsHolder.appdate.setText(details.getApplyDate());
                detailsHolder.lv_type.setText(details.getLeave_type());
                detailsHolder.from.setText(details.getFrom());
                detailsHolder.to.setText(details.getTo());
                detailsHolder.nod.setText(details.getNod());
                detailsHolder.reason.setText(details.getReason());
                detailsHolder.reason.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                detailsHolder.status.setText(details.getStatus());
                //detailsHolder.cb2.setChecked(((View) list.get(position)).isSelected());

                detailsHolder.cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

                    mChecked.put(position, isChecked);    // Saving Checked Position

                    // Find if all the check boxes are true
                      if (isAllValuesChecked()) {

                            MainActivity.cb1.setChecked(isChecked);    //set HeaderCheck box to true
                        }
                  } 
                    else {
                    mChecked.delete(position);     // Removed UnChecked Position
                    MainActivity.cb1.setChecked(isChecked); // Remove Checked in Header
                    }
                    }
                    });

                detailsHolder.cb2.setChecked((mChecked.get(position) == true ? true : false));



                return row;
            }



            // Find if all values are checked.

            protected boolean isAllValuesChecked() {


            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (!mChecked.get(i)) {
            return false;
            }
            }
            return true;
            }

            class DetailsHolder
            {
                TextView empcode;
                TextView empname;
                TextView appdate;
                TextView lv_type;
                TextView from;
                TextView to;
                TextView nod;
                TextView reason;
                TextView status;
                EditText remark;
                CheckBox cb2;




            }




}





    }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37201604/2032561

Comment: on clicking approve button theirs a method 'getData("Yes")'. In that method actual logic is coded.

Comment: still getting same result